# SQL Stored Proc : How to pass a collection of files to a stored proc?

Tags: sql-server

My program has code that saves attachments, I want these attachments to be transferred to the database, and I am going to use a stored procedure to accomplish this.

I need to know what is the @param type to accept an array of binary files?

finally once I have this array, how to I insert this data into a SQL table?

I guess I am looking at using a byte[] for 1 file, but how do I pass from C# or .net a collection of byte arrays to the SP, and what should the param type be to accept this array of byte[]

**Updated**

Need a solution that will work in 2005 and 2008.

**Update**

I've decided to scrap the idea of having 1 large SP to process everything. Instead I am going to have smaller SPs, then handle the transaction in .net.

Do you think this would be a better solution, to handle the transaction in .net data objects?

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using as the answer will differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create just one SP, and call it multiple times, one for each file I need uploaded, and keep the transaction managed in C# code.

Answer (score 1):

If you were needing only to pass an array of values, I would suggest to format them as XML and pass them as the SQL xml datatype. You can perform select from XML with SQL just as easily as from a table.

It may also technically work if you pass binary data in XML, but I'm not sure it will be a good solution. Anyway, it is an option.

Comment: I need to pass an array of byte[] I guess. XML in this case won't suffice surely?

Comment: Xml should work fine for your scenario. See OpenXML:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008, you can use the table-valued parameter feature.

This allows you to define a parameter of a table type, and then supply values to that parameter as a `DataTable` from your C# code.

See these blog posts and articles for more information:

- [SQL Server 2008: Table-valued parameters](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/07/sql-server-2008-table-value-parameters.html)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1483)

This is a new feature of SQL Server 2008, so you won't have this in SQL Server 2000 or 2005.

UPDATE: if you need to support SQL Server 2005 as well, check out Erland Sommarskog's excellent article [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html). It offers a few ideas on how to accomplish this in 2005.

Marc

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that will work in 2005 too. I have however decided to drop 2000 from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

See [Arrays and Lists in SQL 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html). This article aggregates pretty much every technique there is out there and discusses the advantages and problems with each approach.